# WebMatrix startersite progressbar while importing CSV

Tags: c#, csv, razor, import, webmatrix

I'm newbie in building websites I'm using Razor C# in Webmatrix and I need help with progress bar while importing CSV files in my code. Below you can see my source.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Import CSV";
}
@using System.Data;
@using System.Data.OleDb;
@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers;

@{
// Upload File
    var fileName = "";
    if ((IsPost) && (Request["Action"]!="Delete") && Request["Action"]!="Import" && (Request.Files[0].FileName!="")) {
        var fileSavePath = "";
        var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
        fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + fileName);
        uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
    }

// Import File
    bool importSuccess = false;
    if (IsPost && Request["Action"]=="Import"){
        // Initialize connection variables
        string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" +
                                   Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + @"; Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;"";";
        string CommandText = "select * from "+Request["filename"];
        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(CommandText, myConnection);
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        var insertCSV = "";
        var rowNum = 0;

        // Open connection
        myConnection.Open();

        // Fill DataSet
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(myCommand);
        oda.Fill(dataset);

        // Close connection
        myConnection.Close();
        var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");

        // Transactions
        if(Request.Form["ImportType"]=="Transactions"){
            string      var0;
            int         var1;
            string      var2;
            string      var3;
            string      var4;
            string      var5;
            string      var6;
            string      var7;
            string      var8;
            int         var9;
            DateTime    var10;
            decimal     var11;
            decimal     var12;
            string      var13;
            int         count = dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            while(rowNum <= dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count-1){
                var0=dataset.Tables[0].Rows[rowNum][0].ToString();
                var1=Convert.ToInt32(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[rowNum][1].ToString());
                var2=dataset.Tables[0].Rows[rowNum][2].ToString();
                var3=dataset.Tables[0].Rows[rowNum][3].ToString();
                var4=dataset.Tables[0].Rows[rowNum][4].ToString();
                var5=dataset.Tables[0].Rows[rowNum][5].ToString();
                var6=dataset.Tables[0].Rows[rowNum][6].ToString();
                var7=dataset.Tables[0].Rows[rowNum][7].ToString();
                var8=dataset.Tables[0].Rows[rowNum][8].ToString();
                var9=Convert.ToInt32(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[rowNum][9].ToString());
                var10=Convert.ToDateTime(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[rowNum][10].ToString());
                var11=Convert.ToDecimal(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[rowNum][11].ToString());
                var12=Convert.ToDecimal(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[rowNum][12].ToString());
                var13=dataset.Tables[0].Rows[rowNum][13].ToString();
                rowNum++;
                insertCSV = "INSERT INTO Transactions (TransactionType, TransactionNumber, DeliveryAcc, AccountName,  RepCode, CustCode, PartNo, Description, ProductGroup, Qty, TransactionDate, Sales, Cost, InvoiceAcc) VALUES(@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12, @13)";
                db.Execute(insertCSV, var0, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10, var11, var12, var13);
            }
            importSuccess = true;
        }

        // Rep Codes
        if(Request.Form["ImportType"]=="RepCodes"){
            string      var0;
            string      var1;

        // Customer Types        
        }
        if(Request.Form["ImportType"]=="CustTypes"){

        }
    }

// Delete File
    bool deleteSuccess = false;
    var fileNameDelete = "";
    if (IsPost  && (Request["Action"]=="Delete")) {
        fileNameDelete = Request["filename"];
        var fullPath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + fileNameDelete);
        if (File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
                File.Delete(fullPath);
                deleteSuccess = true;
        }
    }
}
<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@Page.Title.</h1>
    <h2></h2>
</hgroup>
<div>
    <h1>File Upload</h1>
    @FileUpload.GetHtml(
       initialNumberOfFiles:1,
       allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:false,
       includeFormTag:true,
       uploadText:"Upload"
    )
    @if (IsPost && Request["Action"]!="Delete" && Request["Action"]!="Import" && Request.Files[0].FileName!="") {<span>File uploaded!</span><br/>}

    <h2>List of available files:</h2>
    @if(deleteSuccess){
        <h5>File @Request["filename"] deleted!!!</h5>
    }
    @if(importSuccess){
        <h5>File @Request["filename"] imported!!!</h5>
    }
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>File Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (string fullFilePath in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"))){
            <tr>
                <td><a href="@Href("~/Uploads", Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath))">@Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath);</a></td>
                @if(Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath).Substring(Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath).Length-3)=="csv"){
                    <td style="width: fit-content;">
                        <form method="post">
                            <select name="ImportType" style="width: auto;">
                                <option value="Transactions" SELECTED>Transactions</option>
                                <option value="RepCodes">Rep Codes</option>
                                <option value="CustTypes">Customer Types</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="@Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath)" />
                            <input type="submit" name="Action" value="Import" />
                            <input type="submit" name="Action" value="Delete" />
                        </form>
                    </td>
                }else{
                    <td>
                        <form method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="@Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath)" />
                            <input type="submit" name="Action" value="Delete" />
                        </form>
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

As you can see my code already imports data and 600,000 records can be imported in less than minute but I want to show progress bar so user can see that website is doing something.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Thomas

Comment: Not going to be easy, what I mean is, there is no api you just import and there you go.

Comment: Usually I do db software in Delphi and what I do is open additional modal window and show everything in there (the window can be closed by cancel button only, so import stops and transaction is not completed). I did not know that website has to be fully loaded to be shown on the screen and then updated by Java for example. I was thinking about opening new modal window with progress bar, etc and then update it by Java. It will be already shown after clicking the import button so it will be fully loaded. I don't know if it's possible to control additional window from main one.

Comment: You won't be able to add a Progress bar, maybe if you do allot of custom work with AJAX calls and all that. But I will post another solution to let the user know that the web application is actually busy at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a javascript JQuery loader, untested but should work.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <link href="css/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function StartLoader() {
            $("<div id='TheLoader'></div>")
                .html("LOADING...")
                .dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    position: ['center', 'middle'],
                    width: 150,
                    height: 90,
                    title: 'Loading',
                    resizable: false,
                    closeOnEscape: false,
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                        $(".ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                    }
                });
        }

        function EndLoader() {
            $("#TheLoader").remove();
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

The `closeOnEscape` and `open` part in the Dialog keeps the user from being able to close the dialog.
Now to start the loading screen, call the `StartLoader();` function from client side, and to close the loader, call the `EndLoader();` function which will remove the div completely.

Sources: [Google](http://www.google.com), [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation), [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

EDIT: I have added a fiddle for the loader, [check it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/sVwDm/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Pierre. I will check it this Saturday. Will let you know results. :)

Answer (score 0):

That is great. Now I know how to show modal dialogues. 
 I changed html attribute of TheLoader

```
$("<div id='TheLoader'></div>")
   .html('Please Wait...<br/><br/><div id="progress-holder"><div id="progress"></div></div><br/><span id="message">...</span>')
```

Is it possible to update width of:

```
<div id="progress">
```

while importing?

I tried with

```
function updateValue(perc) {
    $("#progress").style.width = perc + "%"; }
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, Yes you can try it with attr from Jquery. http://api.jquery.com/attr/ ... It will then be something like $("#progress").attr('style','width:' + perc.toString() + '%;'); //the string should look something like 'width:45%;'; You can also just set the width tag directly on the div... $("#progress").attr('width', perc.toString() + '%'); ... The Jquery '.width()' should also do the trick or '.css()'......... Google for 'jquery set div width' the first 3 to 5 results should help you out

Comment: Hi, That is what I was thinking about but it doesn't work. updateValue(50) doesnt work. I tried function updateValue(perc) {$("#progress").css('width',perc+'%'); $("#progress").attr('style','width:' + perc.toString() + '%;'); $("#progress").attr('width', perc.toString() + '%');}. Even if I execute function during import by calling Razor code just before import @Html.Raw("<script>updateValue(88);</script>"); Is it possible that it doesn't work because page is not fully rendered?

Comment: Yes, that may be the case, or your javascript breaks and that can also be the cause of the javascript not working. Maybe you can try to put the Script right at the end of your page, what will work is if you use $(function(){ //Code here, This code will only run when the page is fully rendered. Document Ready... });